# Match for multiple lines of text between delimiters in Java

Tags: java, regex, multiline

How can I match multiple lines of text between delimiters in Java?

Question best explained by an example:

```
...
unimportant text
EndOfEntry
Key=Value
unimportant text
maybe a few lines of unimportant text
AnotherKey=AnotherValue
EndOfEntry
more unimportant text
...
```

In the above, I want to match on Key=Value.*AnotherKey=AnotherValue having appeared in one entry together. I simply want to know whether or not the pattern appear -- I don't need to replace anything.

However, with the same desired match, if given multiple entries, such as:

```
...
unimportant text
EndOfEntry
Key=Value
unimportant text
maybe a few lines of unimportant text
AnotherKey=NotMyValue
EndOfEntry
RandomKey=Value
unimportant text
maybe a few lines of unimportant text
AnotherKey=AnotherValue
EndOfEntry
more unimportant text
...
```

I wouldn't want the above to be matched successfully, because we don't see exactly Key=Value and AnotherKey=AnotherValue inside a single "entry". Instead, we see Key=Value in the first entry and AnotherKey=AnotherValue in the second entry.

I've been trying with a regex like (and of course \S\s can be replaced by the DOTALL option for Pattern):

```
Key=Value[\S\s]*?AnotherKey=AnotherValue
```

but of course that matches both. I've also tried:

```
Key=Value[^EndOfEntry]*?AnotherKey=AnotherValue
```

but that doesn't work because then there's no dot and we're not matching the newlines at all.

Is there one single regex that can match precisely what I'm looking for? Would it simplify things to strip newlines first or some other two-step processing (which I'm trying to avoid simply for the sake of education)?

Comment: I'm not clear about your need. Can you put a better input example and your desired output?

Comment: `Key=Value[\S\s]*?AnotherKey=AnotherValue[\S\s]*?EndOfEntry` do what you're looking for?  Is each entry guaranteed to begin with Key=Value?

Comment: Nevermind, you need a negative lookaround, as that will match too much in your example.  Regex may not be the right tool here.

Comment: @Fede, desired output should just be matches or not

Comment: @adamdc78, I think you may have already figured this out, but the above will match the second example (incorrectly) in addition to matching the first example (correctly). Is there a solution with a regular expression? Multiple regexes?

Comment: I agree with @adamdc78; trying to do all the work with one single regex isn't the right approach. I would iterate over each line and test for a match. Use a counter or something to keep track of when you hit `EndOfEntry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use:

```
\bKey=Value\b(?:(?!EndOfEntry).)*?\bAnotherKey=AnotherValue\b
```

(with the **DOTALL** flag, as you suggested in your question).

Experiment it live [here on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wL3sK2/3).

---

***How it works:***

I've basically simply replaced your `.*` by that expression: `((?!EndOfEntry).)*`, which represents roughly *anything that doesn't contain `EndOfEntry`*.

In addition, to avoid matching with the pairs `RandomKey=Value` and `AnotherKey=AnotherValue`, since `RandomKey=Value` would also match `Key=Value` (for example), I've added an other little tweak:

I've surrounded your pairs with `\b` (asserts that we're at a word boundary) (or `\s`, for any space character), so we'd only have a match when the entire word is matching.

---

Here's a piece of **Java** code that uses the regex I'm suggesting against your examples:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bKey=Value\\b(?:(?!EndOfEntry).)*?\\bAnotherKey=AnotherValue\\b", Pattern.DOTALL);

final String invalid = "unimportant text\n" +
                "EndOfEntry\n" +
                "Key=Value\n" +
                "unimportant text\n" +
                "maybe a few lines of unimportant text\n" +
                "AnotherKey=NotMyValue\n" +
                "EndOfEntry\n" +
                "RandomKey=Value\n" +
                "unimportant text\n" +
                "maybe a few lines of unimportant text\n" +
                "AnotherKey=AnotherValue\n" +
                "EndOfEntry\n" +
                "more unimportant text";

final String valid = "unimportant text\n" +
                "EndOfEntry\n" +
                "Key=Value\n" +
                "unimportant text\n" +
                "maybe a few lines of unimportant text\n" +
                "AnotherKey=AnotherValue\n" +
                "EndOfEntry\n" +
                "more unimportant text";

System.out.println(pattern.matcher(invalid).find());
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(valid).find());
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work in Java. Even regex101 has the first capture group wrong.

Comment: I think it actually works and I don't see what's wrong with that example on regex101. Maybe I didn't understand the question correctly, though. I'll let the OP have a look at my answer just in case I might be right :)

Comment: Ahh, you made the group causing the issue non-capture.  When I ran it on regexplanet (an actual Java regex tester) it didn't match the supplied inputs.  If you've got working Java code I'd take that over RegexPlanet, though.  I stand corrected.  EDIT: It would have helped if I'd included the valid string as a criterion.  My bad!

Comment: Also not working for my on regexplanet.com: http://fiddle.re/d7x4y6 and click Java. But if it works in Java, I'll take it, thanks! Can the parens become square brackets since capture groups aren't used for replacement?

Comment: Yeap, doesn't work on *RegexPlanet* for the simple reason that apparently going to a newline doesn't correspond to appending `\n`... Simply replace the `\n` by some `\s` or `\b` and it is also working on *RegexPlanet* :)

Comment: You can't replace the brackets with square brackets (square brackets denote a character class rather than a grouping) but (?:) denotes a non-capture group.

Comment: @ccjmne I'm guessing RegexPlanet uses \r\n then.  Pretty easy to deal with but if you don't need to, it would just slow things down for no reason.